# Oracle SQL to show only certain results

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a set of license numbers which are going to retire ('01','02','03')
Some employees have a license number which is expiring AND a license number which will remain active
My results need to show only those employees with a retiring license number
If an employee has both scenarios then they should not be in the results
This is the part where I cannot get it to work

Table: tbl_lcns_num
insert table

My query is

```
Select * from tbl_lcns_num
Where lcns_num in('01','02','03')
AND lcns_num NOT in('04','05','06');
```

I also tried it like this

```
Select * from tbl_lcns_num
Where lcns_num in (('01','02','03') AND lcns_num NOT in('04','05','06'));
```

My table is:

[image: Table]

[image: My result is]

I expected only employee QRS456 to be in the results

I even tried creating temporary tables; one for active license numbers and one for retiring license numbers
I used exists and not exists as applicable and the results are the same.

What should my query be to get the expected results?

Comment: Please show your data and expected results as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

A single `lcns_num` value which is in ('01','02','03') must always *not* be in ('04','05','06') as the values in the list do not overlap.

```
select * from tbl_lcns_num t1
where lcns_num in ('01','02','03')
and not exists (
  select null from tbl_lcns_num t2
  where t2.emp_num = t1.emp_num
  and lcns_num not in ('01','02','03')
);
```

For each row matching the numbers you're retiring, the `not exists` looks for rows for the same employee which are *not* in that list - which at the moment will be 04, 05 and 06 but also allows for other values you haven't shown.

Quick demo:

```
with tbl_lcns_num (pk, emp_num, lcns_num) as (
  select 12345, 'ABC123', '01' from dual
  union all select 12345, 'ABC123', '02' from dual
  union all select 12346, 'ABC123', '04' from dual
  union all select 12348, 'XYZ789', '05' from dual
  union all select 12349, 'XYZ789', '06' from dual
  union all select 12340, 'QRS456', '01' from dual
)
select * from tbl_lcns_num t1
where lcns_num in ('01','02','03')
and not exists (
  select null from tbl_lcns_num t2
  where t2.emp_num = t1.emp_num
  and lcns_num not in ('01','02','03')
);

        PK EMP_NU LC
---------- ------ --
     12340 QRS456 01
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMP_NUM
FROM tbl_lcns_num
WHERE lcns_num IN ('01','02','03')
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT EMP_NUM
FROM tbl_lcns_num
WHERE lcns_num IN ('04','05','06');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tbl_lcns_num Where lcns_num in('01','02','03')
and emp_num not in 
(select emp_num from tbl_lcns_num Where lcns_num in('04','05','06') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily breakdown your requirement into two logical steps:

1. Show all users whose license is expiring
2. Exclude all users who have at least one license which is not expiring.

So, you can use the `MINUS` operator in your SQL statement. Here is the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) to the official docs

I don't have access to an oracle DB right now, but you query should be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMP_NUM
FROM tbl_lcns_num
WHERE lcns_num IN('01','02', '03') 
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT EMP_NUM
FROM tbl_lcns_num WHERE lcns_num IN('04','05','06')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT license1.pk,
       license1.emp_num,
       license1.lcns_num
FROM   tbl_lcns_num license1
WHERE  license1.lcns_num IN ('01','02','03')
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   tbl_lcns_num license2
                   WHERE  license1.emp_num = license2.emp_num
                     AND  license2.lcns_num NOT IN ('01','02','03'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the employee numbers, you can aggregate your records, such as:

```
Select emp_num
from tbl_lcns_num
group by emp_num
having max(lcns_num) < '04';
```

You can add a listagg on the licenses, if you want to show these, too:

```
Select 
  emp_num,
  listagg(lcns_num, ', ') within group (order by lcns_num) as licenses
from tbl_lcns_num
group by emp_num
having max(lcns_num) < '04';
```